# QGIS 3.28: Set the "no data" colour to transparent for multiple rasters?

Tags: qgis, raster, transparency-opacity

I've seen a few answers, all of them several years old, providing python scripts or stitching them together.

Is there not a way to just right click on the group header, set properties and it just applies to all files in the group? This seems eminently sensible. Or a "make like this" setting that copies a select setting from one file to many others the same as you can for styles?

There has to be a way of doing this without doing it individually, taking the file out of QGIS, or breaking out the python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In QGIS 3.32.2-Lima - you can copy a raster style and paste it into multiple raster layers:

[image: Copy]  [image: Paste]